# How to download a text file and store as a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a set of text files representing a table of data from a third party that I'd like to download using a JavaScript application.  They look something like this:

```
col1 col2 .. coln
vala valb .. valz
valA valB .. valZ
etc..
```

I've been trying to use jQuery to do this.  I've been able to use $.load, but I don't want to store the data in the DOM, instead I'd like to parse it out into an object.  Whenever I try to use an of the ajaxy methods I'm getting an error I don't understand.  For example:

```
var myData;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $(this).attr('source'),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        myData = data;
    }
});
alert(myData);
```

Gives me an `undefined` value for `myData`.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the url that you're requesting from your servers or is it a remote resource?

Comment: @Dan Its from my server.  When I test locally, I use a local web server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that code to work the event needs to be syncrounus, in other word, set async: false in the $.ajax-call. The problem comes because ajax is normally async, meaning that when you do the alert, the request might, or might not have finished. Normally though, it won't cause it takes longer time to fetch a page than to do a function-call. So, by setting async: false, you tell jquery (and the ajax-handler) to wait till the page is finished loaded before you try to alert the data. Another method to achieve the same effect is to do something like this:

```
var myData;
function fin(data) {
    myData = data;
    alert(myData);
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $(this).attr('source'),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: fin
});
```

This approach is probably better than to set async to false, because it won't make the browser hang while waiting for the page your loading. However, asynchronous programming is not something that is easy to learn, therefore many will find it easier to use async: false.

Comment: It's better to put everything dependent on myData in the callback function. This way it won't be executed if the request has failed and the browser won't be blocked.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it might be harder for peoples to understand that way of thinking. I've edited my answer with more information on the subject though.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  I'm using the asynchronous example you provided.

Comment: @Rich: Just a hint, the best way to learn how ajax works (the `a` in ajax standing for Asynchronous) is to play around with it. At least according to my experience, getting the hang of how all the async stuff worked was not always easy, at least not when you try to get some value in the middle of some function and don't really see the point in breaking it up into two different functions. Javascript has a **lot** of great answers for cases like that, but all of them requires several times of failing. Once you get the hang of it javascript and ajax are really cool(!!) and powerful.