# Problem in accessing a variable's changed value outside of if block in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var query=getquerystring() ; //get the query string entered by user
        // get the JSON response from solr server 
        var newquery=query;

    $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?", function(result){
            //$.each(result.response.docs, function(result){

                if(result.response.numFound==0)
                {

                $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+query+"&spellcheck=true&json.wrf=?", function(result){


                    $.each(result.spellcheck.suggestions, function(i,item){
                        newquery=item.suggestion;

                    });

                });

                }
```

In the above javascript code a variable newquery initialy having value of query. but when the if condition is true its value have changed. but my problem is i am not getting its changed value outside of if block while i want this changed value. how can i do this.

Please reply.

**EDIT**

Can i make it as:

```
   $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?"
  {
  async:false
  }, 
function(result) {
```

Comment: It’s a terrible idea to use synchronous AJAX requests (`async: false`). Your web page will be painfully slow and clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $.getJson is asynchron.

See this: [How to download a text file and store as a string in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846355/how-to-download-a-text-file-and-store-as-a-string-in-jquery/4846363#4846363)

Comment: Alxandr: Where should i write async: false in $.getJson ??

Comment: You can't. You need to write it async or change the function to `$.ajax`. As specified by http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ , `$.getJSON` is a shorthand for `$.ajax`. However, you should rarely (if ever) use async: false, rather you should just make the program run async. So, in your case, make a function (like the fin-function I wrote) that does what you want to do with the newquery, than call that fin-function from inside the each-loop you got (or outside if you wan't only the last one).

Comment: @Alxandr: i am not getting how to write a function in my case. and i can not use an alert().

Comment: I told you, `$.getJSON` does not support synchronous execution. You have to write it async or change which method you use. And I'm not able to help you with making it async if I don't know what you are trying to do with the returned data.

Comment: Alxandra:In my function  i am parsing the json data which returned by getjson.look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436129/problem-in-accesing-a-variable-outside-of-a-function-in-ajax-call