# Is this a scope issue in JavaScript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it posible to use ajax respone outside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652887/is-it-posible-to-use-ajax-respone-outside-of-it)

I've created the following JavaScript routine that goes to a WCF oData service and gets some data. In the success element I get the results into the results variable and alert them - I see that there are objects returned. When I run the second alert, outside of the ajax call and before returning the results, the results variable is "undefined".

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
function retrieveJsonpODataSet(baseUrl, query)
{
  var oDataUrl = baseUrl + "?$format=json&$callback=?";
  var results;

  $.ajax(
  {
    url: oDataUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: 
      function (data, textStatus, xhr) 
      {
          results = data.d;
          alert(results);  // This shows the results
      },
    error: 
      function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
      { 
          alert("Query failed.\n\n" + oDataUrl + "\n\n" + errorThrown);
          results = null;
      }
  });
  alert(results);  // This shows "undefined"
  return results;
}
```

Please ignore the query parameter - I've not finished the routine yet.

*EDIT*

Initially I had no `async:false` in the ajax call. I've added that now but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: **A** -synchronous. Can someone please write up a FAQ?

Comment: @MukeshSoni Not a scope issue.

Comment: @Mukesh - You're right on the 2nd part... it is a synchronous issue.  It is not, however, a scope issue.  'Results' is defined before the ajax call and the internal closures and will scope through just fine.

Comment: oh ok... i didn't see the declaration for results.

Comment: Consider using deferreds perhaps to maintain scope `$.when(etc).fail(etc).done(etc)` - alerting something that's set inside an ajax call, outsite of that ajax call, is probably the issue.

Comment: Deferreds is just a fancy way of saying "use callbacks".

Comment: @freakish Yes. It's also very handy, simple and even easier to understand.

Comment: @SpaceBison Easier to understand then callbacks?? I doubt it. :) Personal opinion though. Still learning `callbacks` is more important, because it is *JavaScript*, not *jQuery* (some people think they are JavaScript developers, because they know jQuery, hehe). Sometimes you won't be able to use jQuery, for example when you are developing Server-Side JavaScript. But you can (and surely will) use callbacks there.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341810/how-to-return-the-result-from-jsonp-call-outside-the-function or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436129/problem-in-accesing-a-variable-outside-of-a-function-in-ajax-call or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935968/use-variable-outside-the-success-function-from-an-ajax-jquery-call or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532082/return-value-of-post-call or ... I'm exhausted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ajax` call is an asynchronous operation. It fires and your code does not stop at it. So `results` is returned which at that point is undefined. What you need to do is to pass callback to the function.

```
function retrieveJsonpODataSet(baseUrl, query, callback) {
   /* some code */
   $.ajax({
       /* some settings */
       success: function(res) {
           /* some code */
           callback(results);
       }
   });
}
```

Now you use it like this

```
retrieveJsonpODataSet(baseUrl, query, function(res) {
    /* Hurray, I have result now in res variable! */
});
```

**DO NOT USE `async: false` OPTION**! It blocks **ALL** scripts untill the call finishes... and what if it does not finish at all?? You will be blocked forever.

**EDIT**

I've missed that the request is JSONP. In that case `async: false` won't even work (it does not work for cross-domain requests and JSONP). So you have to use callbacks anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to do it to create a function that does return this data? I've got a specific function syntax to work to based on some existing software that I'm creating some pluggable functionality for and I am unable to change the call that's made by that software.

Comment: Without `async: false` there is no such possibility. If the existing software forces you to use it, then the software is really badly written. Or you use it incorrectly. You can fire the call *before* using the software and use the software inside `retrieveJsonpODataSet` callback function.

Comment: I don't know about it being badly written. It just expects to be able to make a call and get results back using javascript. I don't have access to the source code to make this any different.

Comment: @Richard I've updated the answer. With JSONP the thing you are trying to do is impossible. You have to refactor your code. Use `retrieveJsonpODataSet` as first and then use your software inside the callback. There is no other way.

Answer (score 5):

*A fellow Richard!*

This isn't a scope issue, but more of an execution one. Both the `success` and `error` options are event handlers, and run asynchronously (hence it being called AJAX). This essentially means that the `alert(results)` and `return results` can, and likely will, get executed before the `success` or `error` events are triggered.

Comment: Not only *likely*. They will *always* execute before events are triggered, because JavaScript is single-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax is async, so the alert executes before the ajax completes. You need to set the ajax call async property to false in order for script to halt the execution until ajax request is made & processed.

However, jQuery docs says:

async
Default: true
By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.**

Comment: I've just updated that (and the question) but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Ugh, please don't recommend making calls synchronous. Better to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX request are sent, without the script waiting for a response, that's what Dave Newton means by `A-synchronus`, put the alert inside the success callback function, and you'll see what the actual response is.

alternatively, you can specify the `async` property, and set it to `false`, to force your script to wait for the response, before continuing.

Comment: No, it's a jsonp request. Bad advice anyway.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `async: false` either, but it can still be used, even if it's just for debugging purpouses. Overlooked the request being jsonp, though.