# $.GET() didn't return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have script like this.

```
function getContactLastDateOfDeparture(contactId) {
    $.get(
        '/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/'+contactId, 
        '', 
        function(data){
            alert(data);
            return data;
        }, 
        'json'
    );
}
```

I test script above with `console.log(getContactLastDateOfDeparture(2144))`, when in alert phase it outputted string `2011-12-06`, but when phase `return` it outputed `undefined`

How to make the return should be `2011-12-06` ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846355/how-to-download-a-text-file-and-store-as-a-string-in-jquery/4846363#4846363

Comment: @Alxandr at the nuts and bolts of the question, I agree this is the same. But without him knowing the solution, I can see how it doesn't seem the same.

Comment: True. I mainly just posted it cause it was quicker than posting the answer again. I only thought it might help as I explained the problem in some detail in the other question. Not trying to say hist google-foo isn't up to date or anything.

Comment: You need to be more specific when trying to get our attention. Your problem is vague at best!

Comment: @zequinha-bsb I think the problem is clear. He gives a test case, and explicitly states where the problem is and what it is. Just because you got down-voted doesn't mean it isn't a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do a return in an AJAX function, as it is asynchronous. It is better to call another function at the end if you want to pass along the value.

To do this, you can pass it along like this:

```
function getCall(param, callback) {
    $.get('url', function (data) { alert(data); callback(data); }, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your function to return value from the ajax call, you can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of $.get (essentially $.get is based on $.ajax with some simplified params); $.ajax has a parameter "async" that you can set to false to make the ajax call synchronous.

IMPORTANT - it is not recommended to use sync calls with ajax as it will freeze the js execution and might lead to unexpected problems.

Comment: Mentioning this is even a possibility is like giving a kid to play with a sword and tell him to be careful.  People who don't understand how asynchronous stuff works shouldn't know about that possibility, it might seem like an easy fix to them, while what they really need is grasp how event-driven programming works and re-strcture their code to fit that model. Doing synchronous stuff in a single threaded environment is just plain wrong.

Comment: I agree, and I would never advise anyone to do that, thus the side note. I just gave a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://fixingthesejquery.com/images/ajax101.png

You should read up about Ajax, asynchronous behavior and event driven programming. It just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score -3):

Gus,

The first parameter is a url to a valid processing page (html, asp, php, etc).

EDIT (after being voted down):

A valid url, in your case, would be:

```
$.get('url', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

your url '/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/'+contactId would 
not "compute"

However,

```
'/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/getContactID.php?contactID='+contactId
```

would!

Your processing file (.asp, .php, etc) would, then, return the value you are
expecting.

Comment: it is valid url, the AJAX is work. it not just return value. Please see my question above.

Comment: No Gus, it is not a valid url. A url is terminated by a file extension (.html, .asp, .php, etc). In this case, you want us to believe that your parameter "contactId" is a file name? I will be editing my answer so you can understand what I mean; even though Ktash has pointed out the same thing I have.

Comment: @zequinha-bsb This can be a completely valid URL for a lot of reasons. First off, it could be a directory in which a default page will be used. Secondly, it could be using redirects to redirect to a page. Finally, it could be a file without an extension that the server knows how to process and serve. The URL is not really the issue here.

Comment: WOW! To what extent will someone go to prove himself totally wrong? That original statement of his would only work if the parameter "contactId" is a file name. Ktash even went to the extreme to make my clarificarion very clear and still, forced the questioner being right. Geehs. It would only work if the statement was something like: '/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/getContactID.php?contactID='+contactId as I state in my edited answer after the very first vote down.

Comment: @zequinha-bsb The URL is 100% valid. You do not need `.php`, `.html`, or anything to have a Valid URL. In fact, SEO optimization is better if you don't have crazy urls like that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504169/seo-friendly-urls-htaccess

Comment: R-U missing the url  '/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/', when added contactId (+contactId) becomes an invalid url? ... unless contacId is another virtual directory ('.../') or a real file name (....php, .asp, etc)? Are you blind?

Comment: @zequinha-bsb Calm yourself. The example listed in the code given would yield the following: `/transaction/ajaxGetContactLastDateOfDeparture/2144`. This URL is completely valid. I use URLs like this all the time. So does any Wordpress blog. In fact, so does StackOverflow. Look at the URL in your URL bar right now. You will notice that it does not end in `.php` or `.aspx` and I can guarantee you they do not create a new directory every time someone asks a question. Or posts an answer. URLs like this are everywhere and are more friendly for Users and SEO. I'd recommend learning to use them.